# Possible to modify an existing partitioned Oracle table to utilize INTERVAL?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

We have an existing table w/ monthly partitions of data.  The partitions are added, it appears, yearly, via {insert process here we're still researching}.  Trouble came when {X} forgot to add the '22 partitions into the lower environment.

Is it possible to modify the existing table setup & switch it over to INTERVAL (auto generation of newer partitions as needed)?  Or would we need to re-setup:  archive, create new, copy data...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: Post the DDL of the table you want converted

Comment: Version:  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit ProductionOracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production